# How do I solve this error with Scanner class: Exception in thread "main"...?

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[]args) { 
     double num = 0;
     double counter = 0;
     double ncot = 0;
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

     while (!(num == -1)) {

         ncot = scan.nextDouble();
         if (ncot == -1) {
            System.out.println("The average is: " + (double)(num/counter)); 
         }
         else {
           num = num+ncot;
           counter++;
         }
     }
     scan.close();
   }
} 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1465)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
```

The Code it seems to be triggering a error when im running it on Ideone.com but when i run in eclipse it's fine however.

Comment: ideone doesn't have any way to read from the console, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

This is really puzzling.  According to the published source code for the standard versions of `Scanner` (Java 6 and Java 8), the only way that you can get that exception at that point is if something has already called `close()` on the `Scanner` object.

(Note that if you instantiated a Scanner around an input stream that was already closed, or a dummy, or null, you would get a different exception.  This particular exception only happens if the `Scanner` object's private `closed` flag is `true`, and that only happens when you call `Scanner.close()`.)

But with the code you have shown us, that is not possible.  The `Scanner` can only be closed after you exit the loop.

I can think of only two explanations:

1. This isn't the code that you ran on ideone.
2. The guys have implemented ideone have tweaked the behavior of the standard `Scanner` class.  In a way that is inexplicable ... to me.